# img src attribute and browser cache

Tags: caching, browser

clicking on a element in a page, my application change the src attribute of an img element.
I don't understand why firefox gets the images with this http headers:

`pragma no-cache 
Cache-Control: no-cache`

avoiding firefox to use his own cache.

Chrome, for example, doesn't.

Thank you
Luca

Answer (score 0):

Before answer I should add some detail:
1. My application is behind Tomcat 
2. I saw that that headers was added only for file bigger than 512KB

Solution was to modify server.xml in order to have bigger cache object
`<Context cacheMaxSize="40960" cacheObjectMaxSize="2148" docBase="\\mypath\docbase" path="/graphics" />`

see:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Standard_Implementation